# (k)ubuntu 14.10 - graphic artifacts on intel

Tags: kubuntu, intel, 14.10

today i have tried ubuntu and kubuntu 14.10.
I've experienced some graphical artifacts around the cursor.

Following issues have been observed:

- the cursor leaves a line of cursors on fast movement
- cursor disappeared if a input fields cursor is blinking
- moving araund the cursor shows rendering rectange around the cursor

(k)Ubuntu 14.04 works correctly in this cases.
Disabling the Desktop-Effects in KDE fixes the artifacts.

What could i do to fix that?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Any luck with this? just ran into this issue with an intel celeron 3150 proc, and kubuntu 14.04.5